# How do I find the root li of a nested child element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have this navigation:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="wire-nav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Our Company
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    Safety
                    <span class="right-caret"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    Customer Service
                    <span class="right-caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" target="_self">Customer
                            Satisfaction Index (CSI)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>      
</ul>
```

When a user is on the page "customer satisfaction index" (or any child page of "Our Company", I want to bold the root element "Our Company".  How can I target this with CSS and/or jQuery? The class "active" is applied only when a user is on that page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), `$("li.dropdown")`, ... -> [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".active").closest(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
```

**Explained:**

`$(".active")` is the start point.

`.closest(".dropdown")` targets the `<li class="dropdown">` in the ancestors list.

`.find(".dropdown-toggle")` finds what's below within the childs of the previous result.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Our Company
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

So to it, you apply some CSS:

`.css({"font-weight":"bold"});`

---

Look for those documentation pages for more info:

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/),[`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Thanks, it's getting closer but here's the problem: I have multiple submenu items under "our company" with dropdown menus as well as they are all being bolded. So in the code sample above, "our company" AND "safety" are being bolded.

Comment: Actually, I just switched it to this and it works: $(".active").closest(".dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").css({ "font-weight": "bold" }); .children only travels a single level down the DOM tree.